# JQuery Datepicker is working, but Timepicker will not work at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
function applypicker(type, id) {
    if (type == "date") {
        $("#" + id).datepicker();
    }
    if (type == "time") {
        $("#" + id).timepicker();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Date picker is working fine but time picker is not working.

Comment: is there any error.... whether the `$("#" + id)` returns an element

Comment: Which timepicker plugin are you using? As far I know there is no official plugins from jquery-ui for timepicker...

Comment: can you post the rest of your code , like how the call is made what js did you used and etc

Comment: i use jQuery UI - v1.9.1  and there is no error on $("#" + id)

Comment: Error which i got is $(...).timePicker is not a function

Comment: i am not using any plugin i just called this function from other function

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are attempting to use a widget which does not exist.

According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/category/widgets/), there is a datepicker widget for jQueryUI 1.9, but no timepicker. If you want to use a timepicker, you will need to add a timepicker plugin, or make your own.

Comment: but timepicker is working on sibling page which have same js files

Comment: Can you list the JS files you are using?